# Create folder and save image in it using android studio JAVA

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am working with this image editor-like app that is supposed to add text on the image and then save it in "oscfolder". The editing part is done but facing so much trouble with permission issues when I try to create a new folder and save the image as my app has to work on android 4.4 to 13 if anyone can assist me on this I will be tanksful. I have looked at many articles about creating a folder but the folder is not seen when I open internal storage manually and when I save the image inside the Download folder then it can not be accessed from the galley I tried to make a follow-up only end up finding docs that have no any example of shared storage thing.

Comment: On every Android version you can save images to public  DCIM and Pictures folder or a subfolder of those.